# Rails 3.1 Engines Migration Install does not respect migration timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have a Rails app that mounts 3 engines. Each engines has their own db migrations with timestamp in the naming of the migration dating back in 2010xxxxxx-migration-name.rb. After i run `bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations`, all migrations are copied to my app db/migrate but the timestamp of migrations are not respected, they are all re-named to 2011xxxx-migration-name.rb. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migrations are automatically renamed to cause them to *not* conflict with the migrations in your application. They will all be grouped together in one cohesive series of migrations rather than split out through your application.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this problem today while upgrading an old rails app that uses a pre rails 3.1 engine. That engine used the old engine plugin from [lazyatom](https://github.com/lazyatom/engines).

This engines plugin brings it's own migrator class and did not copied migration files into the apps `db/migrate` folder.

If one now uses the rake task to install the plugin files into the app, the timestamp gets updated and `rake db:migrate` tries to run all old migrations again.

#### Easy fix:

Copy all old migrations via `rsync` into the `db/migrate` folder without using the rake task:

```
rsync -ruv FULL_ENGINE_PATH/db/migrate RAILS_APP_PATH/db
```

#### For all engine developers that came from pre rails 3.1 times:

We added an upgrade rake task into [our engine](https://github.com/AlchemyCMS/alchemy_cms/blob/2.0-stable/lib/tasks/install.rake#L28) to handle this. So our users can easily run:

```
rake alchemy:upgrade
```

Comment: Broken link for `our engine`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, took way too long to figure it out:
If a previous migration's timestamp is bigger than current timestamp, new migrations will not use timestamps.

In our case, this was caused by someone who created a migration manually without using the generator